# Javadoc error when using using modules - too many module declarations found

Tags: java, javadoc, java-10, java-module

I have an Eclipse (Photon, 4.8.0) workspace with with three interrelated Java 10 projects that have been configured to use modules.  There is one module-info.java file for each of the three projects.  Eclipse compiles everything fine without any errors or warnings, but when I try to run javadoc I get the error message "too many module declarations found".  The error is reported three times, once for each of the three module-info.java files.

If I remove the module files and simply create classpath dependencies instead of module dependencies, there are no  problems generating the javadoc files that include all three projects.

Comment: Not sure right if this applies to Maven, Eclipse or both, but I think there is only one module-info.java allowed per project. If all three modules are in one project, try splitting it up!